# string.format efficiency with conditional spacing

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

What's the absolute fastest way to format a full name? where the middlename and suffix might be null or empty?

```
string fullname = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", 
                                FName, 
                                MI, 
                                LName, 
                                Suffix);
```

The problem with this is that if the MI or suffix is empty, then I have two spaces.

I could make a second pass with this:

```
fullname = fullname.Replace("  ", " ");
```

or I could just make the string with something like this:

```
string fullname = string.Format("{0}{1} {2}{3}", 
                        FName, 
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(MI) ? "" : " " + MI, 
                        LName, 
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(Suffix) ? "" : " " + Suffix);
```

Is there a better option?  *Fastest* is the important thing.

Comment: If you are not doing it million times then speed should not be a problem.I won't worry about the speed if there are only few calls.

Comment: `string fullname = string.Join(" ", new[]{FName, MI, LName, Suffix}.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)));`

Comment: Not quite a million, but still a lot.  I'll definitely try the .Join at some other time.  Looks nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first for null-or-empty and then write specialized code for each of them. I'd expect directly working on a `char[]` buffer to be faster than `string.Format` or StringBuilder.

But I find it strange that formatting names is a performance bottleneck in your application. Even formatting a few million names shouldn't take that long.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
var parts = new[] { FName, MI, LName, Suffix };
string fullName = string.Join(" ", parts.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
```

It's probably not the fastest solution, but it makes it pretty clear what's going on.

Comment: That's pretty nifty, not what I'd use this time, but something that looks very worthwhile in the future.

Comment: That's what I'd use. It's probably not the fastest approach, but it still processes several million names per second.